# How to use coordinates to open a routermap

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, leaflet, geojson, osrm

I created a map with leaflet 0.7.7 and I add some markers and layer using geojson data.
I would like to add in each marker a link to open OSRM page with starting point centered on the chosen marker.
In my data_marker_layer.js I have such structure

```
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "marker-color": "#0000ff",
        "marker-size": "medium",
        "marker-symbol": "water",
        "name": "Fontana Valle",
        "address": "Via della Valle 19 - VALLE LOMELLINA",
        "description": '<div style="width: 240px; text-align:justify;">Fontanella con acqua potabile, si trova difronte alla Piazza Corte Granda. </div><p text-align="center";><a href="http://www.mappeattive.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/fontanavallelomellina.jpg"><img data-id="2021"  src="http://www.mappeattive.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/fontanavallelomellina.jpg" alt="Fontanella Acqua Potabile" width="240" height="140" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2021" /></a></p>'
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          8.664894998073578,
          45.150788440748805
        ]
      }
    }
```

and the code map for the marker popup is i.e.:

```
function interaction(feature, layer){
    layer.on({
        click: function click (e){var popupContent = "<strong>" +
feature.properties.name + "</strong><br />"+feature.properties.address +"<br />";
if (feature.properties.description) {
popupContent += feature.properties.description+'GPS: '+feature.geometry.coordinates;
}
layer.bindPopup(popupContent,{maxWidth: 320});
}
    })
}
```

How can I write some code to add a link to  "get directions"  and open the OSRM router or Googlemap using the marker coordinate?
I am not a developer so I don't know if can work something like  the use of this.feature.geometry.coordinates

any tips or where I can look for explanations?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a new page with OSRM, centered on and with starting point as the marker coordinates from your map, you would just need to find the appropriate URL to link to.

It looks like an URL template like this works:

```js
"http://map.project-osrm.org/?z=18&center={lat}%2C{lng}&loc={lat}%2C{lng}&loc={lat}%2C{lng}&hl=en&ly=&alt=&df=&srv="
```

With `{lat}` and `{lng}` in decimal degrees of course.

It will center the view on your coordinates and set the start and end points as those coordinates. It looks like you have to specify the end point, and if it is the same as the start point, OSRM map will automatically zoom to max zoom (18)…

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/109/

If you want to integrate the routing within your map, rather than redirecting to OSRM, you would probably be interested in [Leaflet Routing Machine plugin](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/).

Other possible plugins on http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#routing

---

**EDIT:**

Replacing the `{lat}` and `{lng}` in the URL template to include the proper link in your popup content is trivial:

```js
var marker = L.marker(latLng).bindPopup(
    "<strong>" + props.name + "</strong><br />" +
  props.address + "<br />" +
  (props.description ? props.description : "") +
  "GPS: " + feature.geometry.coordinates + "<br /><br />" +
  "<a href='http://map.project-osrm.org/?z=18&center=" + lat + "%2C" + lng +
  "&loc=" + lat + "%2C" + lng +
  "&loc=" + lat + "%2C" + lng +
  "&hl=en&ly=&alt=&df=&srv=' target='_blank'>Get directions from this point</a>");
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/110/

Or using [`L.Util.template`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#util-template):

```js
var marker = L.marker(latLng).bindPopup(
  "<strong>" + props.name + "</strong><br />" +
  props.address + "<br />" +
  (props.description ? props.description : "") +
  "GPS: " + feature.geometry.coordinates + "<br /><br />" +
  L.Util.template("<a href='http://map.project-osrm.org/?z=18&center={lat}%2C{lng}&loc={lat}%2C{lng}&loc={lat}%2C{lng}&hl=en&ly=&alt=&df=&srv=' target='_blank'>Get directions from this point</a>", {
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng
  }));
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/111/

---

**EDIT 2:**

If I understand correctly, you bind the popup in your `interaction` function. So this is where the OSRM link should be added.

The coordinates are available in `feature.geometry.coordinates` as an array where item 0 is the longitude and item 1 is the latitude (as required by GeoJSON spec).

```js
function interaction(feature, layer) {
  var props = feature.properties,
    coords = feature.geometry.coordinates;

  var popupContent = "<strong>" +
    props.name + "</strong><br />" + props.address + "<br />";
  if (props.description) {
    popupContent += props.description;
  }
  // You already access the coordinates, what is the extra difficulty to use them in the OSRM link?
  popupContent += 'GPS: ' + feature.geometry.coordinates + "<br /><br />" +
    L.Util.template("<a href='http://map.project-osrm.org/?z=18&center={lat}%2C{lng}&loc={lat}%2C{lng}&loc={lat}%2C{lng}&hl=en&ly=&alt=&df=&srv=' target='_blank'>Get directions from this point</a>", {
      lat: coords[1],
      lng: coords[0]
    });

  layer.bindPopup(popupContent, { // You can bind the popup right away, and it will automatically open when user clicks on the marker icon.
    maxWidth: 320
  });
  // In your initial code, you bind the popup only after first click on marker, so you need 2 clicks to open the popup!
};
```

Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/McR01O2u8eE7gPZ8qXpI?p=info

Notes:

- In your initial code, you bind the popup on layer click, i.e. the user needs to click once on the marker icon to trigger the binding, and to click a second time to open the popup… Why not binding the popup right away? It will be ready to be opened on user first click.
- You should review how you store your data (in your mapdata file) and how you convert it into overlays. This will save you from dozens of code copy-paste and improve the maintainability of your website.
- Do not forget to [properly credit OpenStreetMap in the corner of your map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)!

Comment: the demo gives the result I like.
My problem is how to get lat and lng from my data file. I have to extract them from the clicked marker position feature.geometry.coordinates but I'm not able to do it in a correct way. 
I need to add a correct code to this codeline
popupContent += feature.properties.description+'GPS: '+feature.geometry.coordinates;
maybe is '<br /> <a href="http://map.project-osrm.org/?z=18&center={lat}%2C{lng}&loc={lat}%2C{lng}&loc={lat}%2C{lng}&hl=en&ly=&alt=&df=&srv=">Get Direction</a>'
but this is not correct of course

Comment: here's a live content I created and I would like either adding a link to the marker or integrate a routing in my existing maps. http://www.mappeattive.com/en/robbio-map/

Comment: It is trivial. I will edit the answer. Note: do not forget to properly credit OSM in your map attribution.

Comment: Great work ghybs! That's exactly enough for me. I will test on my site and give you the right quotation here, as well as the osm contributor attribution

Comment: Hi. Making some code changes following what I guessed from your editing I got this result http://www.mappeattive.com/en/tromello-e/ But you can see I cannot open the right marker on the router. Please, use my page code if you'd like to solve this problem. I have marker data on another file recalled by geojson variable not a simple marker on the page with lat,lng. So I need to retrieve the lat,lng for each marker from those data or maybe I'm a donkey at all

Comment: I have used the code in your question. Please reproduce your issue in an online editing service (e.g. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yRVGz1uD3TGbeRYmYJcq?p=preview)) if you want an answer that is built on your code. You should also edit your question to include more of your code, Plunker should be just an extra convenience.

Comment: here's the full code page http://plnkr.co/edit/QfzL45?p=preview I'd like if you can modify the function interaction to add the router link

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved adapting a snippet I found on another plugin and use google map. I just add this to my code and it works for the little I needed  +'<br /> (<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr='+feature.properties.address+'&t=m&layer=1&doflg=ptk&om=0" target="_blank">Directions</a>)';